# Janela Pop-up Child

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho o seguinte botão que basicamente insere dados de um formulário Web, mas esse botão está num *pop-up child*. O que eu pretendo é que quando correr o botão, depois de inserir o dados fechar a janela do *pop-up*.

Como resolver esse problema?

```
protected void Criar_Fornecedor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            AddItemToListFornecedores(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser);
            string tempurl = currentsiteurl + "/Lists/EntidadesFornecedores/AllItems.aspx";
            SPUtility.Redirect(tempurl, SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse, HttpContext.Current);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SPException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso você esteja usando ModalPopupExtender, você pode fechá-lo pelo code-behind através da seguinte chamada: `ModalPopupExtenderID.Hide();`, no seu método `Criar_Fornecedor_Click`. Logo, ele ficaria assim:

```
protected void Criar_Fornecedor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
       try
        {
            AddItemToListFornecedores(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser);
            string tempurl = currentsiteurl + "/Lists/EntidadesFornecedores/AllItems.aspx";
            SPUtility.Redirect(tempurl, SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse, HttpContext.Current);
            // fecha modal, através do ModalPopupExtender, que se chama ModalPopupExtenderID
            ModalPopupExtenderID.Hide();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SPException(ex.Message);
        }
    } 
}
```

Caso você tenha o aberto via javascript, você pode registrar a execução de um script que fecha seu modal:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "CloseModal", "$(document).ready(function(){closeModal();});", true);
```

Você precisa de um javscript chamado `closeModal();`, já existente, que fecha o seu modal:

```
<script> 
    function coloseModal() {
       // fecha o seu modal - no exemplo a seguir ele é um dialog do jquery        
       $( "#IdDoModal" ).dialog("close");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muito Obrigado a todos, mas resolvi assim.
no meu botão gravar, corre a função "AddItemToListFornecedores" e no fim redirecciona para outra paginja

Codigo Gravar:

```
        protected void Criar_Fornecedor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // alterar o link para a listagem correspondente no sharepoint
                AddItemToListFornecedores(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser);
                string tempurl = currentsiteurl + "/Lists/EntidadesFornecedores/AllItems.aspx";
                Response.Redirect("./ConfirmaFornecedor.aspx?IsDlg=1");


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Redirect("./ConfirmaFornecedor.aspx?IsDlg=1");
            }
            finally
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.close();", true);
            }

        }

    }
```

Codigo da Segunda pagina para fechar o Pop-up:
.ASPX

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">


    function finisheDialog() {
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, 'Cancelled clicked');
    }


</script>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Registo Efectuado com sucesso. Clicar em sair para regressar á página.
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center">
            <input type="button" runat="server" id="btnCancel" value="Fechar"  /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Codigo .CS

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnCancel.Attributes["onclick"] = "finisheDialog()";
    }
```

Comment: Se, seu problema foi resolvido, marque sua resposta como correta.